# How to create js and html css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Responsive width and height for a group of squares

I'm creating a grid of 1:1 squares. The user can keep adding squares and I want the size of the squares to be maintained at their aspect ratio but resize accordingly. The tricky part is I want the square to always be visible on the page - that is to say that there is no scrolling and the webpage would be responsive with width and height.

I have created an example that adds a square every second while testing this. However, I am unable to get it working with the height part. I have been able to get it working with the width.

```js
setInterval(() => {
  console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('square-container')[0]);
  document.getElementsByClassName('square-container')[0].innerHTML += (" <div class = 'square' > < /div>");
}, 1000);
```

```css
.square-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.square {
  position: relative;
  flex-basis: calc(33.333% - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: red;
  transition: background 1s;
}

.square::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="square-container">
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

I'm not using any ui libraries like bootstrap, just vanilla html, css and javascript.

Comment: what about adding height and with of box in css?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to automatically scroll to the bottom on the screen as each square is added. I added this line `window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);` to your code which makes it scroll down as a new line is created.

```js
setInterval(() => {
  //console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('square-container')[0]);
  document.getElementsByClassName('square-container')[0].innerHTML += (" <div class = 'square' > < /div>");
  window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
}, 1000);
```

```css
.square-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.square {
  position: relative;
  flex-basis: calc(33.333% - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: red;
  transition: background 1s;
}

.square::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="square-container">
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Otherwise if you meant that you want the squares to resize so that all of they would all fit to the height of the window that would be different. I had a look around to see if something like this could be done but could not figure it out.